# MVC 4, JQuery 1.9.1, jTable - Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jtable'

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, model-view-controller, jquery-jtable

The Network tab in chrome shows that jquery, jquery-ui, and jtable all load (in that order).

The exception (see title) occurs at the following line:

```
$('#containerDiv').jtable({
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is enough information for anyone to give you an answer? You're going to get responses like: Do you have a div id'd `containerDiv`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the error was caused by duplicate reference of the base jquery.min.js which, to my ignorance, was automatically added at the bottom of the _Layout.cshtml, and the second in the view in which I manually added it.